# В каком виде лучше хранить KeyPair в Android приложении?

Tags: java, android

Хочу написать простой мессенджер и не могу решить как хранить ключи, сгенерированные   KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA"). Изначально я хранил их в виде строк базе данных, но не думаю, что это правильно. Буду благодарен, если подскажите литературу по теме.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, прям вот отвечающей на ваш вопрос литературы не существует, скорее всего. Если есть общее решение по защите информации, которое используют все, то это решение крайне уязвимо. Приходится каждый раз изобретать велосипед.

В целом, если у вас месседжер и переписка шифруется ключами, то сам юзер заинтересован в сохранности этих данных. То есть мы прячем их не от владельца, а от третих лиц. Тогда внутреннее хранилище вполне должно успокоить вашу совесть. На нерутовонных устройствах другие приложения доступа к нему не получат, а большего вам и не потребуется. Если пользователь рутанул телефон и поставил туда недоверенный софт - вы никак не сможете ему помочь.

Если все же хочется прям навтыкать палок в колеса ключеискателям, то добавляем пару "стандартных" мер. Базу данных шифруем. Ключ к бд собирается из IME телефона и какого-то вшитого значения в программе. Вшитое в программу значение собирается из нескольких разных значений, разбросанных по программе. Внутри бд ключ хранится не в чистом виде, а в виде нескольких строк, над которыми нужно провести нетривиальную операцию, чтобы получить реальный ключ. Код программы обрабатываем обфускатором и proguard'ом. Есть еще отдельное развлечение с правкой компилированных классов, но это уже Эребор, имхо. Приведенные меры не сложны в исполнении, но уже заставят злоумышленника потратить достаточно много своего личного времени чтобы добраться до ключей, что 99.99% уже забьют