# Хранение API Tokens в Android Application

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit, token

Пытаюсь подключить свое приложение к серверу. Имеются tokens для получения данных с сервера, но как я правильно понял, хранить такие данные где-то в классе нельзя, нужно более защищенное место. Подскажите, где вы храните данную информацию в своих android-проектах?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/884081/Лучший-способ-для-хранения-токена-в-android-приложении

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [В каком виде лучше хранить KeyPair в Android приложении?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/999879/%d0%92-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b5-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-keypair-%d0%b2-android-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8)